# How do I compile Core 0.8.6 on Ubuntu (EC2)?

Tags: bitcoind, compiling

I'm trying to compile v0.8.6 of the core client from [source](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/releases/tag/v0.8.6), in order to compare IDB (Initial Blockchain Download) performance between versions.

I created a fresh Ubuntu Xenial 16.04 machine on Amazon EC2. I then ran the following commands (which were sufficient for version 0.9.3 and up):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade -y
sudo apt-get install build-essential autoconf libboost-all-dev \
                     libssl-dev libtool pkg-config libevent-dev
```

In addition for this specific version I ran:

```
sudo apt-get install libdb++-dev libminiupnpc-dev
```

I then checked out the source and started the compilation:

```
git clone https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin.git
cd bitcoin
git checkout v0.8.6
cd src/
make -f makefile.unix
```

I'm only interested in running headless `bitcoind`, but I'm not sure if it was already separated form the UI at that release.

I get the following error:

```
rpcrawtransaction.cpp:241:77:   required from here
/usr/include/boost/variant/get.hpp:178:5: error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘boost::STATIC_ASSERTION_FAILURE<false>’
 BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT_MSG(
 ^
makefile.unix:172: recipe for target 'obj/rpcrawtransaction.o' failed
make: *** [obj/rpcrawtransaction.o] Error 1
```

Interestingly 0.7, 0.6 and 0.5 do compile successfully, although they get stuck during IDB, so perhaps compilation just failed silently. I'll make a separate post for those later.

I suspect that I need to install some very specific versions of dependencies, but I'm not sure which and how to go about that. I haven't used Linux in years.

I still have the VM, so I can provide more details if needed.

I'm open to alternative approaches, even using a Windows VM :-)

Comment: 1) [This thread](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/6113) suggests unsetting BOOST_VARIANT_USE_RELAXED_GET_BY_DEFAULT, or applying [this change](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/commit/8b08d9530b93c7a98e7387167ecd2cd5b0563bfb). 2) What's your boost version? PS: Neat project!

Comment: @NickODell `libboost-all-dev` version 1.58.0. I might try the gitian approach first though.

Comment: As for pre-0.8 versions getting stuck in IBD, you'll need to increase the number of BDB locks as described here: https://bitcoin.org/en/alert/2013-03-15-upgrade-deadline.

Comment: @PieterWuille thanks, I actually already did that. They get stuck at different blocks: https://gist.github.com/Sjors/70f14baf1f834f3547bf35553faff610#v072

I might try gitian for those too, because I'm pretty sure the dependencies are a mess on default modern Ubuntu.

Comment: You're using a too recent OpenSSL version which requires strict DER signatures, which only became mandatory in Bitcoin after BIP66. You'll need the patch here: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/5634/files in order to use the pre-BIP66 chain with new OpenSSL.

Comment: P.S. so it took 184 hours to sync. Here's the chart: https://medium.com/@provoost/historical-bitcoin-core-client-performance-c5f16e1f8ccb

Comment: do you know the dependencies that you needed to build 0.8.6 and the other pre-0.8 versions? Thanks for any insight!

Comment: Just to clarify, the versions of the dependencies you used. (e.g., you already mentioned 1.58.0 boost - what about the others? Thanks!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nick ODell [pointed](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/55269/how-do-i-compile-core-0-8-6-on-ubuntu-ec2?noredirect=1#comment64244_55269) me to the [solution](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/6113#issuecomment-298234393):

Edit `rpcrawtransaction.cpp` and change:

```
const CScriptID& hash = boost::get<const CScriptID&>(address);
```

To:

```
const CScriptID& hash = boost::get<CScriptID>(address);
```

This was sufficient to get it to compile.

In addition I applied the OpenSSL [patch](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/5634/files) Pieter Wuille [pointed out](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/55269/how-do-i-compile-core-0-8-6-on-ubuntu-ec2?noredirect=1#comment64263_55269).

You have to do this manually because `depends/packages/openssl.mk` no longer exists, and the function name and signature has changed. Simply open `src/key.cpp` and replace everything inside the `CKey::Verify` function brackets with [this new version](https://github.com/theuni/bitcoin/blob/8dccba6a45db0466370726ed462b9da2eae43bce/src/ecwrapper.cpp#L120-L136).

More than 210,000 blocks synced so far, so I'm assuming this worked.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the gitian build system. Instructions for building 0.8.x with gitian are available here: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/tree/0.8/contrib/gitian-descriptors and here: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/0.8/doc/release-process.md. Using gitian should get you exactly the same binaries as those that were released.

Comment: Thanks, that's a great opportunity to learn about Gitian. I'll mark your answer as Accepted if that works out.

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work out of the box on EC2 (T2):
`sudo /usr/sbin/kvm-ok
INFO: Your CPU does not support KVM extensions
KVM acceleration can NOT be used`

It looks like I would have to use something fancy like [Ravello](https://www.ravellosystems.com/blog/run-nested-kvm-on-aws-google/), or am I missing something?

Comment: IIRC EC2 itself is a VM, so you can't use KVM in it. However, you should be able to use LXC and there are instructions for that at the bottom of the first link I posted (ignore the virtualbox stuff). You will need to do the `make-base-vm` commands with the `--lxc` option too.