# Bitcoind 0.5.3 stuck at block 364,670 - what to do?

Tags: bitcoin-core, synchronization

I compiled bitcoind using the same steps as [last year](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/56439/bitcoind-0-5-3-stuck-at-block-274-011). In particular I set `DB_CONFIG`:

```
set_lg_dir database
set_lk_max_locks 537000
```

Unfortunately once I hit block 364,670 (2015-07-10) I'm treated with:

```
EXCEPTION: 11DbException
Db::put: Cannot allocate memory
bitcoin in ProcessMessage()
```

I tried raising `set_lk_max_locks` to 1000000 but that didn't help. This happens immediately when restarting the node, so it doensn't seem to be a RAM issue.

The `~/.bitcoin/database` looks rather large, assuming this is the equivalent of todays `~/.bitcoin/chainstate` and ``~/.bitcoin/blocks/index`.

```
$ du -s ~/.bitcoin
92047404 # 88 GB
$ du -s ~/.bitcoin/database
42169668 # 41 GB
```

How can I get the synchronization to continue?

Comment: Hey Sjors, I sense a possible implicit question such as "What can I do to make the sync continue?", but could you actually add a phrase what you exactly are looking for in an answer to your post? :)

Comment: I used the exact same wording as last year :-) Added "- what to do?" to the question. The goal is to get it unstuck.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this to continue the download?

Comment: @LeanMan no, but I believe Andrew Chow is trying at the moment (see his answer below).

Answer (score 4):

According to BDB's [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17275_01/html/programmer_reference/lock_max.html), there's actually 4 options controlling parameters in the locking subsystem:

- `set_lk_max_locks`
- `set_lk_max_lockers`
- `set_lk_max_objects`
- `set_lk_partitions`

From my understanding of the documentation, `max_lockers` and `partitions` are not really relevant for Bitcoin as there is not a whole lot of concurrent access to the database, which is what those parameters control.

However, if you look at the `db.log` file, there are entries when the failures occur that point to which parameters need to be increased.

On 0.5.0, the first error I ran into was `Lock table is out of available lock entries`. This indicates that `set_lk_max_locks` needs to be increased, and indeed, increasing it does get past the problem block.

The second error was `Lock table is out of available object entries`, and this I believe is the error you have run into here. This indicates that `set_lk_max_objects` needs to be increased. So this problem can be resolved by doing e.g. `set_lk_max_objects 1000000`, until you run out of locks or lock objects again, or some other problem comes up.